# Помогите мне с вывод текстом с html станицы в RichTextBox C#

Tags: c#

Мне нужно сделать вывод текста с html страницы в `RichTextBox`. Сейчас:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string news = "http://.ru/news.txt";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        siteNews();
    }

     public void siteNews()
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(news);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        richTextBox1.Text = "Новости проекта:\n" + responseFromServer;
    }
```

Comment: Код следует приводить в текстовом виде, а не скринами.

Comment: **html** в **Rich**TextBox? Т. е. вопрос заключается в конвертировании html в rtf? Кажется, тогда лучше придумать какое-нибудь другое решение...

Comment: А разве возможности rtf смогут в себя включить возможности html?